# Calculate stock grouped by several columns from table of purchase and table of sales

Tags: sql, sql-server

1 for purchase called `tbp` and 1 for sale `tbs`. 
here is my code for both with inserted values

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbp
(
    SA varchar(150),
    Product varchar(150),
    Quantity int,
    CPU int,
    CPQ int,
    D datetime,
);

CREATE TABLE tbs 
(
    SA varchar(150),
    Product varchar(150),
    Quantity int,
    CPU int,
    CPQ int,
    D datetime,
);
```

For purchases :

```
INSERT INTO tbp (SA, Product, Quantity, CPU, CPQ, D)
VALUES ('Ahmed', 'i3', 15, 15, 15 * 15, GETDATE());

INSERT INTO tbp (SA, Product, Quantity, CPU, CPQ, D)
VALUES ('Ahmed', 'i5', 15, 15, 15 * 15, GETDATE());
```

For sales:

```sql
INSERT INTO tbs (SA, Product, Quantity, CPU, CPQ, D)
VALUES ('Ahmed', 'i3', 15, 15, 15 * 15, GETDATE());
INSERT INTO tbs (SA, Product, Quantity, CPU, CPQ, D)
VALUES ('Ahmed', 'i5', 15, 15, 15 * 15, GETDATE());
```

I am looking for a query that calculates the stock from both table grouped by SA, Product, Quantity, CPU; and actual time.

Abbreviations: SA = sale agent, CPU = cost per unit, CPQ = cost per quantity, D = Date.

I've tried the following code:

```sql
select 
    SA, Product, Sum(Quantity), CPU, CPQ, D
from 
    (select SA, Product, Quantity, -CPU, -CPQ, D 
     from tbp
     union all
     select SA, Product, -Quantity, CPU, CPQ, D 
     from tbs) dt 
group by 
    SA, Product, Quantity, CPU;
```

I get several errors:

```
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 178  
No column name was specified for column 4 of 'dt'.
```

```
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 178  
No column name was specified for column 5 of 'dt'.
```

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 178  
Invalid column name 'CPU'.
```

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 170  
Invalid column name 'CPU'.
```

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 170  
Invalid column name 'CPQ'
```

Please help, and thanks in advance, I really appreciate your effort

Answer (score 1):

You are getting those errors since you used "-" sign before "CPU" and "CPQ" column you need to mention column names for those columns like:

```
select SA, Product,  Quantity,-CPU CPU,-CPQ CPQ,D from tbp
```

But you will still get an error saying some thing like CPQ is not in group by clause or not in an aggregate function.

Please share your desired results so that I can suggest you appropriate answer.